# Changing the HTML of CKEditor form elements (in the dialog window)

Tags: javascript, html, wysiwyg, ckeditor

I'm trying to modify the HTML of the dialog boxes in CKEditor. The HTML inside each of those boxes is an absolute nightmare, and even worse, the source code is compressed and it's unclear what the path of execution is.

I want to take something like this:

```
<div class="cke_dialog_ui_select" id="44_uiElement" role="presentation"><label style="" for="42_select" id="43_label" class="cke_dialog_ui_labeled_label">Link Type</label><div role="presentation" class="cke_dialog_ui_labeled_content"><select aria-labelledby="43_label" class="cke_dialog_ui_input_select" id="42_select"><option value="url"> URL</option><option value="anchor"> Link to anchor in the text</option><option value="email"> E-mail</option></select></div></div>
```

and turn it into something more legible and easier to style, removing one of the divs. These are for the Image and Anchor dialog boxes (Modal dialogues) respectively.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: in what way are they 'hard to style'? You have a class attribute on each relevant node, it should be trivial.

Comment: If it's trivial, can you do it for me?

Answer (score 1):

Wait, are you really trying to edit the HTML files inside the editor?

There's superb api and documentation.  It's not worth trying to describe here when the documentation says it 100% better and clearer than I ever could.  If you're trying to customize the dialogs, [here's the documentation.](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Dialog_Customization)

[The Developer Guide](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide) for all of the api

And [all of the documentation,](http://docs.cksource.com/) how to's etc.

If you still need help beyond that, give me a heads up.

Answer (score 1):

This is my proposition for this problem.

```
    var htmlId=dialog.getContentElement( 'tabId', 'htmlElement' ).domId;
    document.getElementById(htmlId).innerHTML='<img src="happy_face.jpg"/>';
```

I must say that the documentation is a little bit vague on the proper way of doing this. If someone has a better solution, I would be glad to see.

http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dialog.definition.html

I used native javascript but it could very well be jquery.

```
var htmlId=dialog.getContentElement( 'tabId', 'htmlElement' ).domId;
    $("#"+htmlId).html('<img src="happy_face.jpg"/>');
```

Comment: Very old question but worth an answer.